# Printing basic and very simple histogram with qplot / ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `data.table` like this:

```
   Name       V1
1: factor1    150
2: factor2    250
```

I'd like to have a simple histogram / barplot that shows me two bars next to each other with the equivalent length(150 and 250). I tried

```
qplot(Name, V1, data = data.table))
```

which just shows me a scatterplot - which I would now like to see as a histogram / barplot.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: well if you want an histogram you want qplot(Name, V1, data = data.table, geom="histogram")) but it looks like you are describing a bar plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bar plots can be made by including the geom='bar' and stat='identity'  in the qplot function so it would be like this:

```
qplot(Name, V1, data = data.table,geom='bar',stat='identity'))
```

Comment: The ```stat = 'identity'``` is what I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following code with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.table, aes(x=Name, y=V1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```